# how to write a code select drop down data by values

Tags: python, selenium

```
<select name="relation" 
style="width:180px"><option value="0">relation</option>
                                    <option value="S">Son</option>
                                    <option value="D">Daughter</option>
                                    <option value="W">Wife</option>
                                    <option value="N" selected="selected">NotAvail</option></select>
```

how to write a code select drop down data by values
gives 'module' object is not callable error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('relation'))
select.select_by_visible_text('Wife')
```

Comment: Yes it gives  'module' object is not callable error

Comment: Please do try and make sure to import these two : `from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select`

Comment: In python program i written import webdriver and impot select() also

Comment: Ok i will second one also

Comment: Select does not have `()`, make sure that is not there in code

Comment: Cannot import name select from selenium webdriver.support.ui

Comment: `from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select`

Comment: try the above one, should work for you

Comment: <a href="javascript: d.o(16);" class="node">House Tax</a>
Xpath : //*[@id="dd0"]/div[25]/a[2]